# play/scala , implicit request => what is meaning?

Tags: scala, playframework

Most of the play framework I see the block of code

```
// Returns a tasks or an 'ItemNotFound' error
def info(id: Long) = SecuredApiAction { implicit request =>
  maybeItem(Task.findById(id))
}
```

yes my understanding is define a method `info(id: Long)` and in scala doc to create function in scala the syntax look like this:

```
def functionName ([list of parameters]) : [return type] = {
   function body
   return [expr]
}
```

Can you tell me what is the meaning of `implicit request =>` and `SecuredApiAction` put before `{`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`play.api.mvc.Action` has helper methods for processing requests and returning results. [One if it's `apply` overloads accepts a `play.api.mvc.Request` parameter](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L87):

```
def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result]
```

By marking the request parameter as `implicit`, you're allowing other methods which implicitly require the parameter to use it. It also stated in the [Play Framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaActions#Building-an-Action):

> It is often useful to mark the request parameter as implicit so it can
>   be implicitly used by other APIs that need it.

It would be same if you created a method yourself and marked one if it's parameters implicit:

```
object X {
  def m(): Unit = {
    implicit val myInt = 42
    y()
  }

  def y()(implicit i: Int): Unit = {
    println(i)
  }
}
```

Because there is an `implicit` in scope, when invoking `y()` the `myInt` variable will be implicitly passed to the method.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object X {
  def m(): Unit = {
    implicit val myInt = 42
    y()
  }

  def y()(implicit i: Int): Unit = {
    println(i)
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object X

scala> X.m()
42
```

Comment: Thank you for great explaination,  and SecuredApiAction put before `{` is like an anotation of body expression ?

Comment: still not get your point about this, could more explain on this point, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @steve Where is `SecuredApiAction` defined? Is it a custom class you made?

Comment: the source I am learning from here https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-api-rest-seed/blob/master/app/controllers/Folders.scala

the function define here: https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-api-rest-seed/blob/master/app/api/ApiController.scala

Comment: @steve [`SecureApiAction` is a method](https://github.com/adrianhurt/play-api-rest-seed/blob/master/app/api/ApiController.scala#L33) which accepts an argument of type `action: SecuredApiRequest[Unit] => Future[ApiResult]`. In Scala, you can invoke a method with curly brackets `{ }` or with round brackets `( )`.

Comment: I understood now,thank  you so much.

Comment: @steve You welcome :)